# Aggregate with a threelayered hierarchy as output

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to make a simple mediaserver in Node.JS with MongoDB for it's backend. I'm storing the track metadata in a MongoDB database in the following manner:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53fadfb28024a9b42079820d"),
    "title" : "Welcome To The Machine",
    "artist" : [
            "Pink Floyd"
    ],
    "albumartist" : [ ],
    "album" : "Wish You Were Here",
    "year" : "1975",
    "track" : {
            "no" : 2,
            "of" : 5
    },
    "genre" : [
            "Rock"
    ],
    "disk" : {
            "no" : 0,
            "of" : 0
    },
    "duration" : 446,
    "filelocation" : "F:\\mediaserver\\Pink Floyd\\Wish You Were Here\\02 - Welcome To The Machine.m4a"
}
```

I want to extract artist, album and track information in the following manner:

```
[
    {
        artist: [ "someartist" ],
        albums: [
                    {
                        title: "AlbumTitle",
                        tracks: [ "trackTitleOne", "trackTitleTwo" ]
                    }
                ]
    },
    {
        artist: [ "second artist" ],
        albums: [
                    {
                        title: "AlbumTitle 2",
                        tracks: [ "trackTitleOne", "trackTitleTwo" ]
                    }
                ]
    }
]
```

I've been trying out different statements in the `mongo` shell, and the closest I've got is

```
db.testData.aggregate([
                          {

                           $group: {
                                    _id: "$artist",
                                    albums: { $addToSet: { title: "$album" } }
                                    }
                          }
                     ])
```

which produces

```
{ "_id" : [ "Dave Brubeck" ], "albums" : [ { "title" : "Time Out" } ] }
{ "_id" : [ "Ian Hunter" ], "albums" : [ { "title" : "Welcome To The Club (disc 2)" },    { "title" : "Welcome To The Club (disc 1)" } ] }
{ "_id" : [ "The Band" ], "albums" : [ { "title" : "The Last Waltz <Complete Edition> (disc 2)" } ] }
{ "_id" : [ "Pink Floyd" ], "albums" : [ { "title" : "Wish You Were Here" }, { "title" : "Dark Side Of The Moon" } ] }
```

But as you can see, that output doesn't contain any track info. I thought that something like

```
 db.testData.aggregate([
                       {
                           $group: {
                                    _id: "$artist",
                                    albums: { $addToSet: { title: "$album", tracks: { $push: "$title" } } }
                           }
                       }
                       ])
```

would do the trick, but sadly that tossed me an error:

```
assert: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$push'",
    "code" : 15999,
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
Error: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$push'",
    "code" : 15999,
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
at Error (<anonymous>)
at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:244:5)
at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1149:12)
at (shell):1:13
2014-08-26T13:08:59.094+0200 Error: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$push'",
    "code" : 15999,
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13
```

I've also been checking up on the manuals, but they don't seem to contain any clue on how to perform such a complex query as the one I want to execute.

(Sorry if I break any unwritten rules here on SO, this is my first post.)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Have you looked at the book and author example in the aggregate group documentation? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at those. However, I can't see how I am to get the tracks inside the album object as in a manner mentioned above.

Comment: added your solution as an edit it's a nice ide didn't think of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to built this with double `$group` because why not:

```
 db.test.aggregate({$group : {_id: "$album" ,
                              artist: {$addToSet: "$artist"},
                              tracks:{$addToSet:"$title"}}},
                   {$group: {_id : "$artist",
                             albums:{$push: "$$ROOT"}}})
```

The first one make album documents the second one groups them by Artist. It produces documents of the form

```
{ "_id" : [ [ "Pink Floyd" ] ],
          "albums" : [ { "_id" : "New Album",
                         "artist" : [ [ "Pink Floyd" ] ], 
                          "tracks" : [ "Testtitle" ] },
                       { "_id" : "Wish You Were Here",
                         "artist" : [ [ "Pink Floyd" ] ],
                         "tracks" : [ "Testtitle", 
                                      "Welcome To The Machine" ] } ] }
```

with an addition project

```
{$project:{artist:"$_id","albums._id":1,"albums.tracks":1,_id:0}}
```

it produces

```
{   "artist" : [["Pink Floyd"]],
    "albums" : [{"_id" : "New Album",
                 "tracks" : ["Testtitle"]},
                {"_id" : "Wish You Were Here",
                 "tracks" : ["Testtitle",
                             "Welcome To The Machine"]
                }]
}
```

not exactly what you wanted (I can't get it to rename the `_id`s  in the album array to `title`without it seriously misbehaving and artist is an double array) but maybe a start.

---

**Edit: Final Solution by Trond Humborstad**

```
{ $group: { _id: {album: "$album", artist: "$artist"},
          tracks: { $addToSet: { id: "$_id", title: "$title" }}}},                 
{ $group: { _id: "$_id.artist",
           albums: { $addToSet: { title: "$_id.album", tracks: "$tracks" }}}}
```